# attr() on <link> doesn't take right effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

My jQuery code doesn't work properly when trying to change a 's attribute using attr(), href is set to null, instead of day or night
 Here is my code, does anyone have idea how I may fix it?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css">
```

```
<h1>This is my website</h1>
<button data-file="day">Day</button>
<button data-file="night">Night</button>

<script>
    var link = $('link');
(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var $this = $('this'),
            stylesheet = $this.data('file');

        $this.siblings('button').removeAttr('disabled');
        link.attr('href', stylesheet + '.css');

        $this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
})();

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var $this = $('this'),
```

with this:

```
var $this = $(this),   // No need of any single quotes here for this keyword
```

Comment: Oh, true! Didn't notice that one. Thanks a lot